# **Non**-interactive spell checking

Tags: spell

Given the density of the jargon in LaTeX files, it's much more convenient to spell in batch mode, rather than in an interactive "*would-you-like-to-correct-this-word-by-that-one*" mode.

After `brew install ispell` and `brew install aspell`, I can spell check using one of

```
aspell -c -t file.tex
ispell -t file.tex
```

but both are interactive.

What is the non-interactive variation? `ispell -l -t file.tex` used to work, but this may have been an entirely different ispell (from MacPorts).

Comment: @Andrew Nice.. If you're on macOS, can you mention which aspell you're running? It worked with an `brew install aspell` with `which aspell` reporting `/usr/local/bin/aspell`. But I've suspected there are multiple programs dubbed `{a,i}spell`.

Comment: @Andrew lol... it's confused about its identity itself! Please add your comment as an answer. Also, what is the purpose of the "[[:upper:].*[[:upper:]].*"? Do you wish to remove acronyms or capitalized keywords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the following two bash functions for spell-checking latex documents:

```
function check() {
detex "$1" | \aspell -t list --encoding utf-8 \
           | grep -v -f $HOME/.aspell_exclude \
           | egrep -v '[[:upper:].*:[[:upper:]].*' \
           | sort --ignore-case | uniq | more
}
function slow_check() {
  \aspell -t list --encoding utf-8 < "$1" \
           | egrep -v '[[:upper:].*:[[:upper:]].*'  \
           | sort --ignore-case | uniq | more
}
```

Although, I have to confess that I rarely use the second one.

The `egrep -v '[[:upper:].*[[:upper:]].*'` is there is there to remove the "spelling errors" caused by the `\ref{...}` labels that I use in my documents, which are typically of the form `L:NiceLemma`.

I am using `aspell`, installed from brew, and it reports its version as:

> International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.6.1)